# How can a jest test waitFor a mocked function not to have been called?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

Given an implementation that looks something like the following; in a unit test, how can one assert that a mock of `someExternalCallback` is never called?

```js
const MyComp = ({ isLoading, children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
        someExternalAsyncFunction().then(someExternalCallback);
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Assuming that both external functions are mocked in the test file, and there's a test that looks like the following, how can the inverse be tested?

```js
it("should call someExternalCallback when [...]", async () => {
  // stuff

  await waitFor(() => expect(someExternalCallbackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
});
```

For the inverse, I've currently written a test that looks like the following.

```js
it("should never call someExternalCallback when [...]", async () => {
  // different stuff

  await waitFor(() => expect(someExternalCallbackMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled());
});
```

But I'm assuming the combination of `waitFor` and `.not.toHaveBeenCalled` doesn't actually test the intended situation. My understanding is that `waitFor` calls the callback it's given many times until it passes, but in this situation the test wants to assert that something *never* happens.

Comment: The mock function will _immediately_ not have been called, so even if it subsequently (and unwantedly) _does_ get called your test will pass. Perhaps you could clarify what the "different stuff" is, but possibly 1. that's not an assertion that really makes sense; or 2. really you mean "should not have been called after <X>".

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah you've correctly summarized my concern with the assertion: the assert that is being waited for is **always** immediately true because the test is checking for the absence of something that would take time to achieve. I'm looking for an assert that is grammatically similar to "assert that this given callback never becomes true", with the same reasonable timeouts that are used in `WaitFor`

Comment: The problem with that is that, unlike with `waitFor` where the happy path is the _shortest_, your passing test would _always_ wait the full timeout.

Comment: Yeah great point @jonrsharpe, I've thought about it for a day or so and yeah I think it's not possible / not desirable. If you want to drop in an answer that says "You don't" (in more works) then I'm 'happy' to mark it as accepted.